# Setting Random State in CLISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

So I was using the function `(random 3)` to make a random number between I guess 0 and 3 but every time I ran the program it outputted the number 3 every time and when I tried `(random 2)` it always outputs 1. I looked up what I needed to do and a different post on stack overflow said I needed to initialize the random-state which I assumed I would need to do so I put this code at the top of my program and that's when it went haywire.

```
(setf *random-state* (current-time))
```

After I put this code at the top and ran the program I first got an error that looked like this from the console.

```
*** - Program stack overflow. RESET
```

I tried running the program again and I got this super wacky error.

```
*** - handle_fault error2 ! address = 0x137c9500 not in [0x1a920000,0x1aaa7acc) !
SIGSEGV cannot be cured. Fault address = 0x137c9500.
GC count: 0
Space collected by GC: 0 0
Run time: 0 625000
Real time: 0 543820
GC time: 0 0
Permanently allocated: 92512 bytes.
Currently in use: 2734320 bytes.
Free space: 5 bytes.
```

I then got an error message from Windows that ended lisp.exe and I'm not sure what I did but when the hexadecimal came up I got freaked out. I've looked around the forums and I cannot find a solution to make my random-state code work can someone please help me.

Solution:
Instead of using `(current-time)` I used `(make-random-state t)` which works perfectly fine so my problem is fixed.

Comment: You should put the solution in an answer, not the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*... every time I ran the program it outputted the number 3....*" Where is the code that calls `(random 3)`? Calling `(random 3)` repeatedly should return random numbers between 0 and 2, inclusive, and should never return 3. You will get the same pattern each time you start a new session unless you change the random state used by `random`.

[`random`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_random.htm) accepts an optional random state argument; you don't need to manually set the global `*random-state*` variable, but it can be convenient. Don't rely on things you know from other languages when learning Common Lisp (or any new language), [read the documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm) when you have a question. In Common Lisp a random state is *not* an integer; it is a random state object, and you can create a new one by calling `make-random-state`.

The posted code calls `(current-time)` and sets `*random-state*` to the returned value. Now, `current-time` is not a Common Lisp function; it is specific to Clisp, where it prints the current time as a side-effect, returning `nil`. After setting `*random-state*` to the result of calling `current-time` (`nil`), `*random-state*` is no longer bound to a random state object, and the call to `random` is no longer valid. This is probably why your program "*went haywire*."

Here is an example function which returns a list of random numbers between 0 and `n` (below `n`):

```lisp
(defun random-list (n max)
  (loop for i from 1 to n
        collecting (random max)))
```

Running this from the REPL to create a list of 10 random numbers between 0 and 2, inclusive, and using the default random state. The first line shows the value of `*random-state*`:

```
CL-USER> *random-state*
#S(RANDOM-STATE #*0101001111100011110111001111101110101101110011101101001010001101)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(2 1 1 0 2 2 0 1 1 0)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(0 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 0 2)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(2 0 2 1 0 0 2 2 1 1)
```

You can see that each time the function is called, a different list is generated. This is because the random state (`*random-state*`) has not been reset between calls to `random`. Restarting the REPL and running the program again will produce exactly the same results because the random state is reset to its initial value:

```
CL-USER> *random-state*
#S(RANDOM-STATE #*0101001111100011110111001111101110101101110011101101001010001101)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(2 1 1 0 2 2 0 1 1 0)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(0 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 0 2)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(2 0 2 1 0 0 2 2 1 1)
```

Restarting again, we can try `setf` with `make-random-state`:

```
CL-USER> (setf *random-state* (make-random-state))
#S(RANDOM-STATE #*0101001111100011110111001111101110101101110011101101001010001101)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(2 1 1 0 2 2 0 1 1 0)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(0 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 0 2)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(2 0 2 1 0 0 2 2 1 1)
```

This did not work as expected! We got exactly the same results as when we used the default random state; this is because calling `make-random-state` with a `nil` argument or no argument returns a *copy* of the current random state object. You can call `make-random-state` with `t` as its argument to return a *new* random state object. Note that here Clisp has printed the random state object after the call to `setf`; doing the same thing in SBCL will result in a very different random state object that takes significantly more lines to print.

```
CL-USER> (setf *random-state* (make-random-state t))
#S(RANDOM-STATE #*0101101000011011111101010101100110010101010100001011001111101100)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(0 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 1)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(0 0 2 2 0 2 1 0 2 1)
CL-USER> (random-list 10 3)
(1 2 1 2 0 0 1 0 2 0)
```

Now you can see that `*random-state*` has been set to a *new* random state object, and the resulting lists are different from the previous lists.